# How to configure Laravel application on localhost?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I'm new to Laravel framework. I have installed and developed a small application. I've got source code from Github for an application which I want to integrate and run on my localhost. Please guide me any link or material where I get proper  instructions to start working on this website. Give me details about which file to be edited so that atleast I can access on my localhost.

Github link : https://github.com/fakharkhan/laravel-school-erp

Comment: I don't get your question...If you have developed it  then you can just run php artisan serve in console and you can access it in browser on localhost:8000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use homestead (which is somewhat complex for beginners to setup) follow this:

## steps to setup laravel app from github repo

1. first of all you need to install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).
2. open command prompt (terminal) in your document root folder.
3. clone the repository by executing `git clone https://github.com/fakharkhan/laravel-school-erp.git`
4. change directory in terminal to newly cloned project by using `cd laravel-school-erp` in your case.
5. run `composer install` to install project dependencies.
6. rename **.env.example** to **.env** file.
7. open .env file and enter the database connection information.
8. run laravel migrations (import database) by executing `php artisan migrate` from terminal.
9. visit the url by adding **/public** to it.

### Optional

Setup virtual host by editing httpd-vhosts.conf file (so you can avoid typing **/public** in the url) and adding following to it

```
<VirtualHost example.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    ServerName example.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

then edit your host file and add following to it:

`127.0.0.1 example.dev`

You can replace **example.dev** with whatever URL you like.

Comment: [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "helpers" which does not appear to be
  a file nor a folder

Comment: seems it's issue with this particular project. you should create directory **helpers** in laravel-school-erp and then run `composer install`

Comment: how to configure .env file. how to get all database record same as dat existing project. . now just im getting laravel screen....... how to get all details

Comment: there is only one route(url) defined in the github repo you're using https://github.com/fakharkhan/laravel-school-erp/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php : i think project is no longer maintained by author.

Comment: s may be, there are no pages in resource folder also

Comment: i want to develop a website on school erp. please say me which is the best material to develop this website

Comment: Can you really access the local server by not doing php artisan serve? Oh right this is for XAMPP

Answer (score 3):

You can use Laravel Homestead

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead

Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

You should give a look on [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4). 
This the best way to understand Laravel.

If you just get the source code you'll need to do some things :

- Copy .env.example and rename it .env
- Edit .env file to fit on your needs like database informations
- Run `composer install` to install dependencies
- Run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Im not able to understand properly  how to configure existing files to work for my website

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using xampp on Windows as localhost. Now go to `path/to/xampp/htdocs` then open git terminal by right click on `Git Bash Here`

Now run following commands:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/fakharkhan/laravel-school-erp
2. cd laravel-school-erp
3. composer install
4. cp .env.example .env
5. php artisan key:generate
```

For database connection: make a database and set (DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) values to `.env` file (which is in your project root).

And finally browse: `localhost/laravel-school-erp/public`